# How to cache NodeJS global modules AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, npm-install, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to cache NodeJS global modules on AWS CodeBuild?

I'm using LernaJS to handle my repository and every time build starts I install it with the command `npm install -g lerna` (it takes 30 seconds).

To handle this, first I figured out where npm install Lerna with the command `npm list -g` and was returned

```
/usr/local/lib 
├─┬ grunt@1.0.4 
│ ├── coffeescript@1.10.0 
...
├─┬ lerna@3.14.1 
│ ├─┬ @lerna/add@3.14.0 
│ │ ├── @lerna/bootstrap@3.14.0 deduped 
...
```

Then I tried to cache `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/**/*` folder and I received the following error:

```
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:09:00 Running command npm install -g lerna 
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: npm: not found 

[Container] 2019/05/30 20:09:00 Command did not exit successfully npm install -g lerna exit status 127 
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:09:00 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:09:00 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm install -g lerna. Reason: exit status 127
```

So I checked the content of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` I had these packages:

```
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:19:11 Running command ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules 
grunt 
grunt-cli 
lerna 
npm 
webpack
```

My last attempt was cache `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/**/*`. This way no error is thrown, but cache doesn't work either:

```
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:30:00 MkdirAll: /codebuild/local-cache/custom/656f09faf2819a785eae5e09f5d26a44ff4f20edf155297d6819c9600540cd26/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna 
[Container] 2019/05/30 20:30:00 Symlinking: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna => /codebuild/local-cache/custom/656f09faf2819a785eae5e09f5d26a44ff4f20edf155297d6819c9600540cd26/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna 

...

[Container] 2019/05/30 20:30:01 Running command npm install -g lerna 
/usr/local/bin/lerna -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lerna/cli.js 
+ lerna@3.14.1 
added 650 packages from 321 contributors and updated 1 package in 40.628s
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to save Lerna as `grunt`, `grunt-cl`, `npm` and `webpack` (inside `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`) before building starts?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by cached? what docker image are you using to run your code builds?  if you are just using the AWS provided ones, could you just create your own docker image with your dependencies already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JD D comment, I've created a docker image, pushed it to AWS ECR and use it as my own image.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts
RUN npm install -g yarn lerna
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y groff less && \
  apt-get clean
RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip -o awscli-bundle.zip
RUN unzip awscli-bundle.zip  && \
  ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws && \
  rm awscli-bundle.zip
```